# FETCH num rows with array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I am using pdo to fetch data if email and password is same but it giving me an error and not fetching data below is the code .........

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $email      = $_POST['email'];
  $password   = $_POST['password'];
  //Encrypt Password
  $encrypted  = md5($password);

  //Include Database Connection
  require 'assets/_conn.php';
  $result = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email= :email AND password= :password");
  $result->bindParam(':email', $email);
  $result->bindParam(':password', $encrypted);
  $result->execute();
```

Here is the problem data in not fetching ....

```
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if(count($rows) > 0) {
    foreach($rows as $row){
       $image  = $row['image'];
       $pic    = array('1.jpg',$image);
    }
}
```

Comment: _it giving me an error_ What error?

Comment: Undefined variable: query

Answer (score 2):

**[PDO::FETCH_NUM](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)**

> returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result
>   set, starting at column 0

So instead of using column name use indexing

```
$image  = $row[2];// your indexing
```

And you need to add `image column in your query` . Your query would be

```
$result = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT email, password, image FROM users WHERE email= :email AND password= :password");
```

Comment: You need to add image column in your query

Answer (score 1):

for fetching data you should used to `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` 
like below

and as mention @Saty please add image column into your query.

```
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$pic = array();
if(count($rows) > 0) {
    /* foreach($rows as $row){
       $image  = $row['image'];
       $pic  = array('1.jpg',$image);
    } */
    while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        /*its getting data in line.And its an object*/
        $image  = $row->image;
        $pic[]    = array('1.jpg',$image);
    }
}
```

i hope this is working for you.

Thanks

Comment: thanks reniskhunt but its not working it not fetching data  error coming is Undefined variable: pic

Comment: it's not possible men just check your code. are you used $pic variable outside of while loop?

Comment: @StackOverflow if you used $pic variable outside f while loop then you should define the variable before while loop.

Comment: CHeck this code ....     $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if(count($rows) > 0) {
    while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $image  = $row->image;
        $pic    = array('1.jpg',$image);
    }
}                                               its in loop and print this $pic outside the loop       <?php 
   for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
    echo"<option  data-img-src=\"$pic[$i]\" value=\"$pic[$i]\" ></option>";
   
  ?>